# Browser based IDE - Textarea with code completion available?

Tags: javascript, textarea, code-completion

Recently I discovered it's possible to have syntax-highlighting in a `<textarea>` using JavaScript.

Are there Open Source libraries which also support auto completion?
I'd like to make a simple online editor for HTML/CSS templates.

Preferably, the completion is can be extended, so I can add custom rules.

Comment: Sounds like a cool idea, but not very practical yet. I guess you could utilize HTML5 to cache most of it for off-line use.

Comment: @xil3: what would I have to cache offline? The code completion definitions? They could be inlined as JSON

Comment: so someone would always need an internet connection to use the IDE? Even if the code completion definitions were in-line, that would need to be cached somewhere in order to access this off-line.

Comment: @xil3, ah I see. yes HTML5 makes sense in such cases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check [this wikipedia page on javascript based code editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors). It lists the MDK-Editor as one that supports auto-completion for html, css and javascript. You can see a [demo](http://www.mdk-photo.com/editor/) here.

Answer (score 3):

[CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net) has ability to support autocompletion

- JS example: http://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html
- XML example http://codemirror.net/demo/xmlcomplete.html

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla Labs has  [Skywriter](http://mozillalabs.com/skywriter/) **(This project is no longer active)** which is a browser based IDE. I don't know if it has code completion (I couldn't find it) though.

Comment: Skywrite has been renamed to [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/), the editor which is used in the [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/).